# Unable to execute MR job as user 'foo'

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera-cdh

On a secured cluster, I am unable to execute a simple MR job. It fails to login to Kerberos I guess. Here is some relevant info

```
[foo@klx-1 root]$ yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 2 4
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 4
18/06/05 12:38:13 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:foo (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
18/06/05 12:38:13 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
18/06/05 12:38:13 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:foo (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "klx-1.mydomain.com"; destination host is: "klx-1.mydomain.com":8020;
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:786)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:757)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:756)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
    ... 46 more
```

Here are the steps I carry out

```
 1. su foo
 2. kinit foo@REALM.COM
 3. yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 2 4
```

I do not have the keytabs for `foo` as I provide the password when I do `kinit`. I am really not sure at this point what is wrong. It is a 2 node cluster, I have created the `principal` in kerberos and I have the user `foo` on both linux nodes.

Comment: I guess `hdfs groups` fails the same way...?

Comment: To activate the Java and Hadoop debug trace for Kerberos, search for GitBook _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ by Steve Loughran, and read chapter "Low-Level Secrets". Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are missing a JAAS conf. If you are not familiar, you can [read about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html).

Your conf will be something along the lines of:

```
// jaas.conf
Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=false
    useTicketCache=true
    principal="user/domain@realm";
    };
```

Then you need to pass this flag to the application:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/your/jaas.conf
```

The way to pass the flag is up to you and your setup.

You can:

- Set it in your mapred-site.xml

  ```
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/your/jaas.conf</value>
  </property>
  ```
- Set it in HADOOP_OPTS

  ```
  export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/your/jaas.conf"
  export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="$HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/your/jaas.conf"
  ```
- Pass it to yarn

  ```
  yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 2 4 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/your/jaas.conf
  ```